# Big holes in the Landsat record?

Tags: landsat

Does anyone know why there are multi-year gaps in the Landsat record in some places? This screenshot is from earthexplorer, but I found the whole when my Earth Engine code wouldn't run because it couldnt' find imagery. I was skeptical but, lo and behold, there is a >6 year gap in coverage of this path/row (and those around it that are part of my Earth Engine analysis). I had a similar error in an area of Brazil that I suspect also has a multi-year coverage gap.

[image: Why u no has data?]

Answer (score 2):

It occurs due to several reasons, but [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/4/609/htm) mentioned some reasons which I will quote from it:

> However, **a number of sensor, ground station and data communication
> issues, and variable mission acquisition strategies**, reduce the
> acquisition frequency [3,5,6,7]. These effects, **combined with cloud
> obscuration at the time of Landsat overpass** [8,9], result in Landsat
> reflectance time series that have missing observations at various
> aperiodic times of any year.